# Adding fields to Access table from a form

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, ddl

I have some users who receive a list of items from another group, the number of items on the list can vary greatly (1 - 500).  They have an Access 2010 database now that has an input form with ten spaces to enter the item # and description.  Is it possible to modify this form to only have one input field for the item to start with and then add a button that will run an ALTER TABLE query to add a new field on the form?  The second part is how to sequentially name the fields, for example as they are created I would want them named item1, item2, item3 etc.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this question is screaming subtable. If you find yourself adding fields dynamically, it almost certainly means that you should just create another data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new table that will hold your extra items. Foreign key it back to the table that the form is bound to, and include two fields, `Name` and `Value`.

Something like:

```
tblItemExtraInfo
----------------
ItemExtraInfoID  (pk)
OrigItemID   (fk)
Name (e.g. item1)
Value
```

In this way, your additional data items effectively become name-value pairs, and you don't have to deal with messy DDL in the middle of your form. Worse, IIRC, the database needs to be opened exclusively in order for DDL to be executed, which means nobody would be able to be in the db at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can I dynamically add the input fields to the form as they are needed?

Comment: Use the `CreateControl()` method. MSDN Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221167%28v=office.11%29.aspx